# javascript - Add property to object literal and return

Tags: javascript, object

I have object literal what I consider as base object:

```
var obj = {
   key1   : 'value1',
   key2   : 'value2'
}
```

and would like to use this object and pass it to function with extention like

```
myFunction( obj + { key3 : 'value3' } );

// param became:
{
   key1   : 'value1',
   key2   : 'value2',
   key3   : 'value3'
}
```

or

```
myFunction( obj + { key2 : 'new value2' } );

// param became:
{
   key1   : 'value1',
   key2   : 'new value2'
}
```

`+` operator is not correct for it. How I can do it? Is it a way ?

EDIT: Do you want to permanently alter `obj`? - No, I would like to able to reuse it for next call as base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're okay with altering `obj`, just change it before you pass it:

```
var obj = { /* stuff */ };

obj.key3 = 'value3';
myFunction(obj);
```

---

> Do you want to permanently alter obj? - No, I would like to able to reuse it for next call as base.

Okay, so you need to [make a copy of `obj`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20object%20clone), and alter the copy — either before you call `myFunction`:

```
var obj = { /* stuff */ };
var extension = {key3: 'value3'};

myFunction($.extend({}, obj, extension));
```

or pass `obj` and the "extension" to `myFunction`:

```
var obj = { /* stuff */ };
var extension = {key3: 'value3'};

myFunction(obj, extension);
```

and have `myFunction` do the work:

```
function myFunction(base, ext)
{
    if (typeof base === 'object' && typeof ext === 'object')
    {
        base = $.extend({}, base, ext);
    }

    // rest of the function logic here
}
```

If you're already (or don't mind) using jQuery, [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) will be your best friend for the task.

Comment: Do you want to permanently alter obj? - No, I would like to able to reuse it for next call as base.

Answer (score 23):

With ES2018 or TypeScript 2.1 you can use the [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).

```
// properties on the right overwrite properties on the left

// Overwrite properties from obj
myFunction( { ...obj, key3: 'value3' } );

// Don't overwrite properties from obj
myFunction( { key3: 'value3', ...obj } );
```

With ES2015 you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
// Object.assign(a, b, c, ..) - copy properties from b to a, then from c to a etc.

// Overwrite properties from obj
myFunction( Object.assign({}, obj, { key3: 'value3' }) );

// Don't overwrite properties from obj
myFunction( Object.assign({ key3: 'value3' }, obj) );
```

---

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9p8lh1?file=index.js)

```js
var obj = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}

console.log('-- Object Spread --');
console.log({ ...obj, key3: 'value3' });
console.log('overwrite');
console.log({ ...obj, key2: 'NEW2' });
console.log('no overwrite');
console.log({ key2: 'NEW2', ...obj });

console.log('-- Object Assign --');
console.log(Object.assign({ key3: 'value3' }, obj));
console.log('overwrite');
console.log(Object.assign({}, obj, { key2: 'NEW2' }));
console.log('no overwrite');
console.log(Object.assign({ key2: 'NEW2' }, obj));


console.log('-- Original Object unchanged --');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: The second ES2015 example can be shortened to `myFunction( Object.assign({}, obj, { key3: 'value3' }) );`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that extends objects nondestructively (not "extend", really, just make a new object from another one), for example:

```
var oldObj = {name: 'foo'};

function extendNonDestructive(src, newProps) {
  function F() {} F.prototype = src;
  var newObj = new F;
  for (var p in newProps) {
    if (newProps.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      newObj[p] = newProps[p]
    }
  }
  return newObj
}

var newObj = extendNonDestructive(oldObj, {lastName: 'bar'}); // Doesn't touch oldObj
```

Note: You might be interested in [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which is way more flexible than the little "function F() {}; F.prototype = src;" in my code, but it's ES5+.

Comment: This is pretty much what `$.extend` does — just without the jQuery `;-)`

Comment: And without altering the original. And I don't know that he's using jQuery

Comment: Totally valid point about jQuery, though `$.extend()` doesn't have to alter the original - just pass `{}` as the first argument. I edited my answer after realizing that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add properties to an existing object and return the new object in one line, you can use a combination of the [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and Object.entries functions:

```js
console.log(
   Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries({
      t:4,
      f:2
    })
    .concat(
      Object.entries({
            q:2,
            p:9
      })
    )
  )
);
```

This also works if you want to just modify a single property of an existing object, just, for the new object properties, add the object you want to replace, i.e.:

```
....concat(Object.entries({t:2}))...
```

would just modify the `t` property of the original object.